# how to pass a variable value to another view properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ivar

i have two views **MainView**  and **MainInvoicing**

from **MainView** i am sending a int type variable value to **MainInvoicing**

this is my code

in ***MainInvoicing.h***  file i declared int type var

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myChoice;
```

in ***MainView.m*** file on a button click i am calling the MainInvoicing as

```
MainInvoicing *invoicing = [[MainInvoicing alloc] initWithNibName:@"Invoicing" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:invoicing animated:YES completion:nil];
invoicing.myChoice = 1;
```

from this my **MainInvoicing** is called perfectly, but *myChoice* is equal to zero '0'. while it should be '1'

i am receiving this value in **MainInvoicing.m** as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self Start];
}
```

and the start method is

```
- (void) Start
{
switch (myChoice)
{
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"value is %d",myChoice);
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"value is %d",myChoice);
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Oooopppss...%d",myChoice);
        break;
}
}
```

i am always on default part ….

where am i wrong or any suggestion to get the right value … please help…

Comment: Move this line invoicing.myChoice = 1; before you present viewController.

Comment: @Greg thanks man, you are always helpful …. it works… :)

Comment: Would you like me to add this as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @Greg yes of course ,,, add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign value before you present view controller:

```
 MainInvoicing *invoicing = [[MainInvoicing alloc] initWithNibName:@"Invoicing" bundle:nil];
invoicing.myChoice = 1;
[self presentViewController:invoicing animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

As Greg said in his comment, it's all about order of code.  If you look at your code you should see the order in which it is called.

```
MainInvoicing *invoicing = [[MainInvoicing alloc] initWithNibName:@"Invoicing" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:invoicing animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self Start];
        switch (myChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"value is %d",myChoice);
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"value is %d",myChoice);
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Oooopppss...%d",myChoice);
                break;
        }
invoicing.myChoice = 1;
```

So you are trying to access the `myChoice` variable before you set it, which is why you are getting 0 instead of 1.

With all of that said, there is a possibility of your code working as it is written since the `viewDidLoad` function is not always called serially.  But you should not expect it to always work and you should initialize variables before you call code that could use them immediately.

Accept Greg's answer, I was just adding a bit of explanation to the problem.